# A circle with $n$ lattice points on it's boundary

Tags: contest-math

Given $n$, is it possible to find a circle in the plane with exactly $n$ lattice points on it?

I misread a problem that asked to show that the above has an affirmative answer with "$n$ lattice points on it" replaced with "$n$ lattice points contained in it", thus motivating the question.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669809001012

Comment: The wording is ambiguous; showing AT LEAST $n$ points is easy, showing exactly $n$ might be tricky (if true)

Comment: Yeah, I meant the tricky one

Comment: you can sort the lattice points based on the distance from the center point. Then just pick radius to be large enough that N nearest points are inside the circle?